# How to add a ScrollView without changing the visualization of the other elements?

Tags: android, scrollview

Currently I am having 2 pictures per row (loaded via Picasso) with a checkbox at the top right corner of each of them. When I try to add a Scrollview, the position of the checkboxes get changed and there is an extra row that appears. how can I add it and keep the rest of the visualization in the correct order? here is my code so far (for a row):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linLay"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text=""
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text=""
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the properties of your UI Elements as Right and Left of parent UI element.

```
android:layout_below="@id/name"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/description"
```

Edit: 
I make this Example Code for you: This is not the Exact, you can take idea from this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check this Link: [Layout File - Positioning Item to Right of Another Item (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305789/layout-file-positioning-item-to-right-of-another-item-android)

Comment: Which of the UI elements should be positioned accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same visualization, unfortunately

Comment: Use Layout Properties One by one and debug it.

Comment: @user6456773 please upvote my answer And select it as Accepted Answer