# Add progress bar on the right of a button? (Simple)

Tags: android, xml

I have this layout below. My goal is to keep the progress bar and the button below the TextView and the progressBar directly on the right of the button. What should I change?

[image]

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="hello guys"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="my button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `Button` and `ProgressBar` inside `RelativeLayout`. Then move `Button` to center of `RelativeLayout` with `layout_centerInParent="true"` and finally set `ProgressBar` aligned to right of button with `layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonID"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="hello guys"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="my button" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonID"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do I **center** *the button* in the middle below the textview and add the progress bar to the right of button?

Comment: sisa? hello ok ,

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: check answer again

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. With `RelativeLayout` you can use `toRightOf`

Please research more before you ask a basic question

[Layout File - Positioning Item to Right of Another Item (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305789/layout-file-positioning-item-to-right-of-another-item-android)

Comment: but I want to keep the progress bar and the button below the TextView . don't I need a vertical linear layout for that? please post some code . thanks for answering

Comment: RelativeLayouts also allow you to use `layout_below`. Again, please look at SO questions and documentation before you ask a question